# How to Perform Incremental Historical Data Load from SQL On-Premise to Azure Blob Storage with Dynamic Folder Structure?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I need to extract data from multiple SQL Server On-premises tables to Azure Blob Storage with a historical load dated before 2023-12-17. However, for each table, I need to store them in dynamically created folders following the structure year/month/day/tablename.parquet.

I have a similar process in which I perform a full load with multiple tables, using a control table that lists all the tables I wish to load. This process involves using lookup and foreach activities, as shown in the print below:

[image]

[image]

[watermarktable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY5Cc.png)

Has anyone implemented a similar solution, or can you suggest an approach to achieve this?

Cheers,

Comment: Can you explain your requirement in detail with sample data?

Comment: **`I've managed to copy the data using Lookup activity and ForEach in Azure Data Factory, leveraging a watermark table that contains columns for my queries, table names, and date columns.`** -- What does the watermark table contain?

Answer (score 0):

- In order to load incrementally, you can add a column in watermark table called `watermark_value`. This value is a marker which indicates the point in time up to which the data is loaded to sink. For initial load, store the value as `1900-01-01` , since you have mostly timestamp as watermark column in all tables. Once the load is completed, update the watermark table with the latest value (maximum value) of that timestamp column from the loaded table.
- Take the lookup activity and foreach in outer actvity. In Lookup activity, give the watermark table. Pass the table name, watermark column and watermark value from lookup activity to Foreach activity.
- Inside foreach activity, take two lookup activities. One to get the watermark value from the watermark table and other to get the maximum timestamp value from the source table.

**Query in Lookup1 to get the watermark value:**

```
select @{item().WatermarkValue} as WatermarkValue from WaterMarkTable
 where TableName=@{item().Table_Name}
```

**Query in Lookup2 to get the watermark value:**

```
@concat('select MAX(',item().WaterMarkColumn, ') as NewWatermarkValue from ',item().Table_Name)
```

- Then connect the output of lookup1 and lookup2 to copy activity. In copy activity, give the below query in source dataset.

**Query in source dataset of copy activity:**

```
select * from @{item().Table_Name} where @{item().WaterMarkColumn} > '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.WatermarkValue}' and @{item().WaterMarkColumn} <= '@{activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.NewWatermarkValue}'
```

- Create the stored procedure in SQL database to update the watermark table with new values after every pipeline run.

**Stored procedure to update watermark:**

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE update_watermark
 @LastModifiedtime datetime @TableName varchar(100) AS  
BEGIN 
 UPDATE watermarktable 
 SET [WatermarkValue] = @LastModifiedtime 
 WHERE [TableName]= @TableName
END
```

- In ADF, next to copy activity, take the execute stored procedure activity and add the stored procedure name which is created in above step. For the Stored procedure parameter value,
  LastModifiedtime = **@{activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.NewWatermarkValue}**
  TableName = **@{item().TableName}**

**Pipeline image inside foreach activity:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Aswin, In my sink , I need to create historical folders for partitioning my data by year, month, and day, using the 'filename.parquet' format. The data should be dynamically organized based on my watermark column. Is this possible?

Comment: How are you doing it for full load? It should be similar approach here also.